# How to put histogram with ggplot in the beginning of axes (0,0)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, axes

I want to create a histogram, but I have problems with putting it in the beginning of axes (0,0). Currently it is shifted in the right which looks not good. I expected expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) to solve this. I know it might be answered already but all solutions I've found didn't work. Thank you if you point where is the problem. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x= dataset$count)) + 
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 3,
                       col="blue", 
                       fill="darkblue") + 
        labs(title="Retweets Distribution") +
        labs(x="Retweet number") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,250)) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,250)) + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)
```

And the plot:

[image: Histogram]

Also the summary of count column:

[image]

Comment: Based on what you've provided, it would seem that there aren't `count` values less than about 24.

Comment: I agree with @jdobres. Can you please provide a snippet of the `dataset`?

Comment: @jdobres I was thinking about it, but there are a lot of values close to 0. I tried `table(dataset$count)` and it showed me the summary

Comment: I also agree with @jdobres. you should check the distribution of `count variables`. `summary(dataset$count)`

Comment: Strange . . . One thing is that if you specify a `data` argument for `ggplot()` you can just use the variable name: `aes(x = count)`

Answer (score 0):

Plots will automatically have padding between the edge of your plot area. So even if you set the axes to start at 0, you will have space between the plot area and the margins.

As you have not provided a dataset, here is a reproducible example on how to fix it. You can change the `expand` option WITHIN the `scale_x_continuous` to remove this padding:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

In your case, you will have to use `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,250), expand=c(0,0))`

If you then wish to shift the whole graph left, simply alter the limits.
E.g.

`scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20,250), expand=c(0,0))`

> See the package documentation for more details: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. However, I've tried to use smaller subset and it worked.

Comment: @Jake Here the problem is different, it doesn't seem to be a default plot margin issue. As you mentioned data are not available, but looks like the distribution of values simply don't start at 0 becquse the smallest values available in input are highter than 0 (probably around 25 from the what I see on the plot).